# Testing if a controller works in angularjs using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, spyon

I have some issues when I'm trying to test a method controller.
So, here is my controller, named contactCtrl

```js
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular.module('routerApp').controller('ContactController', function ($scope, contactRepository) {

        $scope.saveContact = function(selectedContact) {
            $scope.errors = [];

            contactRepository.saveContactInfo(selectedContact);

            $scope.contactSelected = false;
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $scope.contactSelected = false;
            $scope.selectedContact = null;
        };

        $scope.selectContact = function(contact) {
            $scope.contactSelected = true;
            $scope.selectedContact = contact;
        };
    });
}());
```

Here is my contactRepository

```js
'use strict';

(function () {
    angular.module('routerApp').factory('contactRepository', function() {
        return {
            saveContactInfo: function (selectedContact) {
                console.log(selectedContact);
            }
        };
    });
}());
```

And here is my spec file named contactCtrl.spec.js

```js
describe('Controller',function() {

    var scope,contactCtrl;

    beforeEach(module('routerApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
       scope = $rootScope.$new();
       contactCtrl = $controller('ContactController',{$scope:scope});
    }));

    describe('ContactController', function() {
        it('save method should have contactSelected false', function() {
            expect(contactCtrl.contactSelected).toBe(false);
        });
    });
})
```

I want to test if when I run the save method actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to actually call the function and then assert the value is what you expect. All of this needs to be done on your `scope` variable rather than controller.

```
describe('ContactController', function() {
    it('save method should have contactSelected false', function() {
        expect(scope.contatSelected).toBeUndefined();
        scope.saveContact('foo');
        expect(scope.contactSelected).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

If you want to check that your controller method calls your factory method you will need to create a spy and then check that spy has been called after you call the controller function:

```
describe('Controller',function() {

    var scope,contactCtrl, contactRepository;

    beforeEach(module('routerApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _contactRepository_) {
       scope = $rootScope.$new();

       // inject your factory so we can spy on it
       contactRepository = _contactRepository_;
       contactCtrl = $controller('ContactController',{$scope:scope});

       // create spy
       spyOn(contactRepository, 'saveContactInfo');
    }));

    describe('ContactController', function() {
        it('save method should have contactSelected false', function() {
            expect(scope.contatSelected).toBeUndefined();
            scope.saveContact('foo');
            expect(scope.contactSelected).toBe(false);

            // assert that function was called
            expect(contactRepository.saveContactInfo).toHaveBeenCalled()
        });
    });
});
```